# Awk regex issue

Tags: regex, awk

here is a sample of my input that I have to work with:

```
Mon Jun 21 05:01:05 2021
Mon Jun 21 06:59:36 2021
Mon Jun 21 07:50:12 2021
Mon Jun 21 08:05:14 2021
Mon Jun 21 08:24:12 2021
Mon Jun 21 09:12:10 2021
Mon Jun 21 10:27:12 2021
Mon Jun 21 10:37:36 2021
Mon Jun 21 11:52:18 2021
Mon Jun 21 12:00:10 2021
Mon Jun 21 12:00:57 2021
Mon Jun 21 12:01:11 2021
Mon Jun 21 12:01:57 2021
Mon Jun 21 12:02:02 2021
```

With AWK, I would like to match all the lines that matches some criteria and also the lines where the time starts at 12pm.

Here is my awk command but it doesn't work:

```
awk -e '/CSF.1/&&/Mon Jun 21/&&/12:\d{2}:\d{2}/ { print$0 }' /var/log/radius/radius.log
```

As you can see my regex for the timestamp is `12:\d{2}:\d{2}` because I want to match a certain time pattern 12:xx:xx but it actually doesn't work at all.

Any help ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your `awk` program in following manner.

```
awk  '/Mon Jun 21 12:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/'  Input_file
```

***OR*** you could even shorten above code to:

```
awk  '/Mon Jun 21 12(:[0-9]{2}){2}/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

- You need to have condition to check `/CSF.1/` as per your shown samples its NOT present in any of your lines hence NO line will be printed here. (In case you have CS.1 in your lines NOT shown in current samples, then you can have code like: `awk  '/CFS\.1/ && /Mon Jun 21 12:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}/'  Input_file` ***OR*** `awk  '/CFS\.1/ && /Mon Jun 21 12(:[0-9]{2}){2}/' Input_file`  don't forget to escape `.` here to make it literal character)
- `\d` is not supported in `awk` regex Engine, you need to change it to `[0-9]` here.
- You need to pass any `-e` option here to `awk` program if you are thinking it works like `sed`, no that is not the case here.
- You need to write `{print $0}` that is taken care by `awk` program by default if any condition is TRUE.

Comment: That is working, thank you. The lines in the file had more information than the sample I put on my post so that's why you didn't see`/CSF.1/`. My issue however, as you mentionned was that I used `\d`but I have to use [0-9] instead. Thanks a lot !